# I want something nice to say about this series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\alpha-k)!}$$ where $\alpha\in A\subset(0,1)$

Is this valid:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\alpha-k)!} < \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(\alpha + (1-\alpha)-k)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1-k)!}$$

But now I have something like $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(-n)!}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $n!$ when $n$ is not a natural number? Are you familiar with the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)? And in what context did you come across this series?

Comment: In case you mean $-n!$ as $\Gamma(-n)$, then you are fine. In that case the inverse Gamma function is convergent.

Comment: Started thinking about factorial of real numbers and I ended up here. So you are saying that the above is ok. So I can indeed bound this series by the sum to infinite of $\Gamma(1-k)^{-1}$?

Comment: Maybe it could be helpful to look up analytic continuation to negative part for $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: Thanks kolobokish. above I have made a mistake because 1-k is a non positive integer for k > 1. But From what I can gather $\Gamma(\alpha - k)$ is valid for all k.

Comment: You could tell the series you like its haircut.

Comment: What if he/she thinks you are lying to make him/her feel better?

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Surely a series with such a nice haircut wouldn't be so upright.